How would I decide on the best LED intensity for TCS3200 sensor
This is for a custom project to detect fluid color and turbidity (a reduction in light passing through) using an Arduino micro, a TCS3200 sensor, and an LED. The tube sits in a custom housing, and the LED shines from the other side and passes through it. It doesn't have to be absolutely correct, but rather, it gives reliable results.
The idea is to measure the color and turbidity of the human fluids that will be passing through this tube and check if they are indicative of infection. Some sort of early warning system before the microbiology results come back. I will be cross-referencing the values I will be getting from an industry-standard spectrophotometer: https://www.pce-instruments.com/english/measuring-instruments/test-meters/spectrophotometer-pce-instruments-spectrophotometer-pce-csm-1-det_6019666.htm
I'm trying to set it up so the LED doesn't shine so bright that it "drowns out" the light sensors and not so dim that it doesn't show the correct colors.
What would be the best method for deciding on which resistance to use? Is there a suitable method other than getting a big selection of resistances and trying them one by one? Maybe a potentiometer?




Code that I am using currently.
   // TCS230 or TCS3200 pins wiring to Arduino
#define S0 8
#define S1 9
#define S2 10
#define S3 11
#define sensorOut 12
 
// Stores frequency read by the photodiodes
int redFrequency = 0;
int greenFrequency = 0;
int blueFrequency = 0;
int cLearFrequency =0;
 
void setup() {
  // Setting the outputs
  pinMode(S0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S3, OUTPUT);
 
  // Setting the sensorOut as an input
  pinMode(sensorOut, INPUT);
 
  // Setting frequency scaling to 20%
  digitalWrite(S0,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(S1,LOW);
 
   // Begins serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  // Setting RED (R) filtered photodiodes to be read
  digitalWrite(S2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(S3,LOW);
 
  // Reading the output frequency
  redFrequency = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW);
 
   // Printing the RED (R) value
  Serial.print("R = ");
  Serial.print(redFrequency);
  delay(100);
 
  // Setting GREEN (G) filtered photodiodes to be read
  digitalWrite(S2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(S3,HIGH);
 
  // Reading the output frequency
  greenFrequency = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW);
 
  // Printing the GREEN (G) value  
  Serial.print(" G = ");
  Serial.print(greenFrequency);
  delay(100);
 
  // Setting BLUE (B) filtered photodiodes to be read
  digitalWrite(S2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(S3,HIGH);
 
  // Reading the output frequency
  blueFrequency = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW);
 
  // Printing the BLUE (B) value
  Serial.print(" B = ");
  Serial.println(blueFrequency);
  delay(100);
 
  // Setting cLear (L) filtered photodiodes to be read
  digitalWrite(S2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(S3,LOW);
 
  // Reading the output frequency
  cLearFrequency = pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW);
 
  //printing the light intensity
  Serial.print(" L = ");
  Serial.println(cLearFrequency);
  delay(100);
}


I've omitted one other part from the photos that hopefully ensures the receptor is enclosed within the black chamber. Not enclosing it will cause heaps of trouble; you're right.
I'm not an engineer by trade(neurosurgery resident), so I'm not really familiar with this logbook. I'm keeping notes in Trello on what issues I've run into and my solutions to them. I would be happy to check any sources you can suggest.
Unfortunately, I haven't got the slightest clue about those devices, but I am willing to learn if necessary.

Thanks for the pointers... I'll keep these in mind.

Enough said, I guess.  I'll remove them now. Just distracting others at this point.

Basics
Cool project!
You should know about potentiometers
So, if you should really go with resistors, you'd honestly just buy an adjustable resistor, a so-called potentiometer (the ones meant for "rare" adjustments are called "trimmer") and try out until you find the best resistance, and keep its position. That's something you'd definitely do here! You buy a fixed resistor, which alone limits the current to the LED to the nominal current at maximum brightness (so that you don't burn anything, ever), and put that in series with your potentiometer, which you can adjust from roughly 0 Ω to whatever series resistance you need to make the LED shine "nearly not at all", according to the LED datasheet. That really depends on the LED and especially its color, so you'll really need an LED's datasheet voltage/current curve to figure that one out.
There's types of LEDs, and some are better suited to your problem than others
You have a small problem here: you seem to be using a single white LED. There's two types of white LEDs:

RGB types, which actually contain a red, a blue and a green LED. Additive color mixing makes that look "white" (to humans). The color emitted by the LED changes with the voltage (which defines the current) applied across the LED, because while all three individual diodes have the typical exponential diode behaviour of current vs voltage (and intensity of the individual LED is proportional to current through it), they have different factors in the exponent – the red LED will still shine at much lower voltage than the blue one. Your analysis will have to account for that!
Phosphor types, which contain a blue or ultraviolet LED, coated by a phosphor which converts the high-energy monochromatic photons to photons from the LED to photons of a wide, continuous range of wavelengths, i.e., actual white light. Here, reducing the amount of photons hitting the phosphor will not change the light spectrum (temperature might still, to a lesser degree).

So, you'd want to pick an LED whose white light is made using phosphor, and not using RGB "subdiodes". Any white LED datasheet contains a "intensity vs wavelength" curve. If it looks like this
(both figures are from this answer by Szymon Bęczkowski):

that's R, G and B LED in a single package. If it instead looks like this:

that's the phosphor-based LED you're after. They're not really significantly harder or more expensive to get, but you need to check what you buy. In fact, you can buy both for benign prices. But: you need to have an LED with a intensity-vs-current datasheet anyways, to dimension the maximum resistance of your potentiometer, so that's not an additional complication!
Note that you sensor's datasheet also shows that your sensor has a wavelength region where it's very sensitive to differences in color – anything with wavelengths < 750 nm – and a region where it just can't tell different colors apart; all shades of infrared look the same to it, but it is very sensitive to them! So, when choosing your LED, make sure its emission curve (as shown above) has dropped off significantly at wavelengths above ca 700 nm.
Advanced stuff: Adaptive Gain Control
Usually in signal processing, we deal with unknowns, arising from noise, temperature, component ageing (LEDs become less bright with time!), material degradation (your transparent tubing might become clouded with time etc). So, you can rarely "adjust manually once, and then it works forever".
I'd like to add that since you're really only after changes in the transmission behaviour of your experimental setup, you could have what is typically called adaptive gain control (AGC) in your system loop (the loop here is: microcontroller setting the current through your LED, the LED shining a thus defined amount of light, the light going through your material, the light hitting the sensor, the sensor being observed by the microcontroller; the microcontroller then adjusting the current if the light is too bright or too dim).
In that case, you would do the following:

make your readout faster; no Serial.print in between measurements. These take random amounts of time (so they ruin all determinism), and are much slower than your readouts.
make your readouts more robust; instead of asking "how long does one single, noisy period take?", you should be asking "how many periods are in this fixed amount of time?"; considering the frequencies we're talking about are roughly between 12 kHz and 20 kHz, it would seem to me that counting for 50 ms would give quite robust numbers
Take the clear channel readout, and define a target value; for example, 360 counts in 50 ms. Calculate the difference between the "is" and the "target" value.
use this difference as "brightness error"; apply a low-pass filter (and here, a simple single-pole IIR "exponentially weighted moving average" would do) to that error, and use it to decide whether to increase or decrease the duty cycle of one of your PWM units
low-pass filter your PWM output (or use it do drive a buck converter) with a simple RC and use that to feed your LED.

The idea here is that the low-pass filtering of the brightness error makes the LED brightness change, but only slowly so, such that you can still detect changes in color without being disturbed by all the 4 channels of your sensor being "disturbed" all the time. That way you always operate your sensor close to an optimal intensity, but can still sense abrupt changes in flow properties.

I appreciate the in-depth answer! It's somewhat challenging to grasp for me, but I'm sure I'll figure the details out eventually. :) One question, though (I've already emailed the supplier, but I'm not sure I'll get a good answer): Is there a visual clue as to how these RGB and phosphor-based LEDs look? I have four-legged RGB diodes, but the ones I've bought as "white" seem to have a simple/single diode inside.

as said, no, you need to look into the datasheet. LEDs with four legs are definitely RGB LEDs, however.

Thanks. In the worst-case scenario, I'll buy some more LEDs from a company that does provide datasheets.

I've linked to an electronics distributor in my answer; all LEDs come with datasheets (I wouldn't even know where to buy ones that don't)

It seems like suppliers in Turkey are not aware of that rule (even the most popular ones). I've found some somewhat shady suppliers who decided to just slap in a link to the manufacturer's PDF file. Which was a broken link but included the file name, which enabled me to find this LED: https://www.arrow.com/en/products/334-15t1c1-4wya/everlight-electronics
And the wavelength chart seems to be in order... Thanks a lot again.
(I've noticed the link you gave me, but I'd rather not go through the process of importing...)

@BilalBahadırAkbulut Digikey is really just an example; E-KOM is their Turkish import partner; should be pretty painless. mouser.com.tr is directly in Turkey (I know that a client of a client of mine ordered replacement parts directly from there), that shouldn't be a problem at all. tr.farnell.com, rs-components… the list of large distributors that directly have Turkish sales goes on. Don't go for anything sketchy.

I contacted the sales company from which I got my original parts (from the grant), and they supplied me with the datasheet. So it's all good, thank you.

@BilalBahadırAkbulut great to hear!
